# algorithm for lines connecting rectangles

Tags: javascript, connection, gantt-chart

I am looking for an algorithm or sample solution for drawing connection lines between rectangles. In my case rectangles are elements Gantt chart and connections show depenedencies. I am using the Raphael JS library to draw rectangles and lines. So a solution in JavaScript would be the best, but an algorithm in meta language or other JS similar will be nice also.

I have found [an example that looks nice](http://sammyjoeosborne.com/Examples/Connector/ConnectorExample.html) but maybe someone knows something else.

In my case there are a few relevant requirements:

1. only horizontal and vertical lines are allowed
2. lines should not cross each other
3. lines should not cross rectangles
   I hope to achieve something similar to this:

[image: Visio Gantt chart]

Comment: this question is alive? well may with the HTML5 canvas you could make some like this or with KinecticJS

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you are looking for **javascript gantt** charts. Check out this one's:

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml

- Editable chart
- Full control with JavaScript API
- Multi-browser/multi-platform support
- Loading from XML
- Serialization to XML
- Movable/resizable activities
- Built-in edit menu, plus custom dhtmlxMenu support
- Extended properties pop-up
- Optional tree view
- Customizable task subscription
- Percent-complete shadings
- Dependency arrows
- Fast and smooth rendering
- Built-in constraint checking
- Print-friendly mode

http://www.bryntum.com/products/gantt/

- Built entirely on web standards - HTML/CSS/JavaScript
- Use with any server (PHP, Java, ASP.NET)
- Supports dependencies, lead/lag and critical path
- Export to PDF/PNG, MS Project import
- Project, task and resource calendars
- Unit tested with Siesta

http://gxt-scheduler.com/

- Built entirely on web standards - HTML/CSS/GWT
- Integrates with any type of backend
- Fully themeable, requiring only basic HTML/CSS knowledge
- Drag & drop and resize items easily
- Supports all major browsers

http://gantter.com/

- google drive integration
- FREE cloud-based project scheduling

http://gantt.twproject.com/

- in-place editing
- drag&drop
- zooming
- do/undo
- multiple dependencies
- full editing
- dates shortcuts
- css skin
- multiple browser
- resources editing
- multiple assignment
- milestones
- export data in JSON format
- resize & scroll